# Are kitnios made in a kosher for pesach oven permitted according to the kitzur?

Tags: passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

Kitzur shulchan aruch chapter 117 halacha 4

All forms of kitnios are forbidden. Similarly, all dried fruit is forbidden unless it is certified as having been prepared on eeds or on an oven in a manner that is kosher for pesach.

The word being used here "וכן", does this connect the prohibition of kitnios to the exception that is applied to dried fruits or are dried fruits prohibited like kitnios are forbidden unless they are prepared in the manner stated as the exception after "וכן"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The "and so on ..." refers to two prevailing Ashkenazic customs at the time. A.) Kitniot. B.) Dried fruit.

(One of the Kitzur's sources is the Chayei Adam, who has a section called: "the customs -- kitniot, and dried fruit.")

Thus:

A.) Kitniot is prohibited by Ashkenazic custom [out of concern for cross-contamination.]

B.) Dried fruit is also prohibited by Ashkenazic custom, out of concern for cross-contamination, but if you dried the fruit yourself in your own kosher-for-Passover oven, that wouldn't apply.